# Nginx virtual host only serves static file on www variant of domain

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have a Nginx virtual host configured for my `domain.co.nz` and `www.domain.co.nz` website on my Ubuntu 18.04 VPS. The file for the virtual host sits within the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory.

It correctly serves the website with a root of `/var/www/domain.co.nz/html` and index of `index.html` for both the www and non-www variants of the website.

In the same directory (the root) as the `index.html` file there is a PDF file called `file.pdf`.

The file shows on `www.domain.co.nz/file.pdf`, the www variant of the domain, but when you navigate to the same URL but without the `www` subdomain, the file doesn't show and instead the index is served. It's not a redirect as the file name stills shows in the URL.

Please find my Nginx config for the virtual host below:

```
server {
        server_name domain.co.nz www.domain.co.nz;
        root /var/www/domain.co.nz/html;
        index index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location ~ /.well-known {
                allow all;
        }


        listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co.nz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.co.nz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
        if ($host = domain.co.nz) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot


        server_name domain.co.nz;
        listen 80;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

The second server block was automatically generated by Certbot.

I'm a bit stumped as to what might be causing this.

I've validated my config using `sudo nginx -t` and there are no errors or warnings.

Comment: Did you reset the browser's cache between configuration changes?

Comment: @RichardSmith ah yeah, it appears to have been a caching issue as it is now working. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks to have been a caching issue as the PDF file is now showing for both www and non-www versions of the URL. I'm unsure however if this is a browser cache or a server-side cache.